# How to position div exactly left to the clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I having one div in my code which is hidden by default.now i wanted to show that div 
    exactly left whenever show button clicked by user.There are many show buttons in my page that's
     why i wanted to show div as mentioned above

```
    <div id="menu" style="display: none;">
       <!-- div content here -->
    </div>
       <button id="showBtn">Show</button>
```

Comment: @cs04iz1 Using Twitter Bootstrap just to place a `div`, really?!

Comment: Do you mean `#menu` have to be displayed next to each button once clicked ? What is the question exactly ?

Comment: @EdenSource i have button whose position could be anywhere in the page and on that button click i want to show hidden div exactly left to the button

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way (and least reliant on Javascript) is to switch the order of the button and the menu in the markup:

```
<button id="showBtn">Show</button>
<div id="menu" style="display: none;">
<!-- div content here -->
</div>
```

This allows you to take advantage of the button's :focus state to trigger a display of the corresponding menu.

```
#showBtn:focus + #menu {
  display: block!important;
}
```

This says "when the button is focused, find the immediately following menu and display it". The !important is necessary to override the inline style.

Comment: Good idea but maybe OP wants this behaviour persistent even button lost focus. A CSS only is possible but require different HTML markup using e.g a label and a checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to change the display style to 'inline-block' when the button is clicked.

```
<div id="menu" style="display: none;">Test
   <!-- div content here -->
</div>
   <button id="showBtn" onClick="$('#menu').css('display', 'inline-block')";>Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the top/left position of your button to dynamically position your `#menu` element :

```
$(".show").on("click", function () {
    var topPos = $(this).offset().top;
    var leftPos = $(this).offset().left - $("#menu").width();
    $("#menu").css({
        top: topPos + "px",
        left: leftPos + "px"
    }).fadeIn(100);
})
```

[Live exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/kcy4cp0b/)

Comment: thats what i am looking for but it is not working in my project

Comment: Maybe you can try to tell me a bit more about your project. I cannot do much so far. Sorry sir.